# Split GL_CODE Column into different columns based on the " . " without using Function in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a query to seperate "GL_CODE" into different columns based the "." as the delimiter.

I have attached a screenshot of the setup i have done, but im getting error after extracting the 7th segment.

Note that the elements in each are not having same string length for every line.

Code that I have used:

```
select 
    YEAR, PERIOD, AMOUNT, 
    SUBSTRING(GL_CODE, 1, 3) AS segment1,
    SUBSTRING(GL_CODE, CHARINDEX('.', GL_CODE, 1) + 1, CHARINDEX('.', GL_CODE, (CHARINDEX('.', GL_CODE, 1)))) AS segment2  
FROM 
    TAG_ENTITY_GL_YTD_BAL
```

[image]

Comment: Images of data, and code, don't help us help you, so its difficult for us to see what's wrong with that. I've marked this as a duplicate anyway, which shows you how to split delimited values into columns. I suggest the answer that uses XML.

Comment: my requirement is to do this in SQL Server Management Studio 2018. I don think the other answers are of help to me.

Comment: *"I don think the other answers are of help to me."* Why not? What doesn't help about them? SSMS is just an IDE, it's not an RDBMS.

Comment: Could you please help me by modifying the script as per my need.
This is how i need it :
   SELECT
    YEAR, PERIOD, AMOUNT, 
    SUBSTRING(GL_CODE, 1, 3) AS segment1 FROM 
    TAG_ENTITY_GL_YTD_BAL

Similarly each GL_CODE should be sepearted as segment 2, Segment 3, ..Etc

Comment: i'm not familier by using functions in SQL.

Comment: Like I said, have a look at the [XML Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15108499/2029983). If you fail to implement it, then post a new question, showing your attempt (**not** an image), and explain why it didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

This has probably already been answered on stackoverflow. Here for example:
[How to split a comma-separated value to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns)

Depeneding on your version of sql server, there are probably better options than the accepted one in the question. Like for example using the built-in string_split function

Comment: The STRING_SPLIT function is not supported in SQL Server Management Studio 2018

Comment: *"The STRING_SPLIT function is not supported in SQL Server Management Studio 2018"* `STRING_SPLIT` was added in SQL Server 2016; the version of SSMS you are using has nothing to do with it's availability, @AkshayRamesh . Your statement is completely wrong as the version of SSMS and whether you can use `STRING_SPLIT` has no relation.