# PROGRESS DB extract string between semi colons - INSTR Function error

Tags: t-sql, openedge, openquery, progress-db, instr

I'm querying a Progress DB via an OpenQuery in MS SQL Server.

I have a field (addr) that contains a string value in the below format:

```
text123; text 456; text 789; text 1011
```

I need to extract each value before the semi colon ; for separate columns

In T SQL I would do this using the below to extract the first part:

```
SELECT
SUBSTRING(addr,1,CHARINDEX(';', addr,1) - 1)
FROM MyTable
```

However, in Progress there is no CHARINDEX, but INSTR

This is my Openquery:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY (MyServer, 'SELECT addr, SUBSTRING("addr",1,INSTR('';'', "addr",1) - 1) as test FROM MyTable')
```

But I receive the following error:

```
OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MyServer" returned message "[DataDirect][ODBC Progress OpenEdge Wire Protocol driver]Error in row.".
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Why are you storing delimited data in the first place? Why not split the string in the outer query? There was literally a [question asking how to do](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60053079/2029983) this a few questions ago in [tag:sql-server] (and it's a very common question anyway).

Comment: Hi @Larnu its from a 3rd party system that I have no control over.  All I have is read only access to it.

Comment: What if you do that on the SQL Server side? instead of `Select * from OPENQUERY(...)` do `Select SUBSTRING(addr,1,CHARINDEX(';', addr,1) - 1) from OPENQUERY(...)`

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yes I can, but wanted to do in the OpenQuery so the Progress server actually performs instead of SQL Server first bringing all the info across then doing it.  If I can't work it out, I will do it on the SQL Server side.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would handle this...

**PostgreSQL:**

```
WITH -- YUOUR TEXT HERE:
someString AS (SELECT 'text123; text 456; text 789; text 1011' AS txt), -- Can come in as a variable
a          AS (SELECT N FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS x(N)),
iTally(N)  AS 
(
  SELECT 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
  FROM   a, a AS b, a AS c, a AS d
),
ngrams(N,Token) AS
(
  SELECT     N, SUBSTRING(txt from N::integer for 1)
  FROM       iTally
  CROSS JOIN someString
  WHERE      N <= CHAR_LENGTH(txt)
)
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS ItemNumber,
  (N+1)                          AS ItemIndex,
  len                            AS ItemLength,
  SUBSTRING(ntxt from 1 for len) AS Item
FROM       ngrams
CROSS JOIN someString
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (VALUES(SUBSTRING(txt from (N+1)::integer for CHAR_LENGTH(txt))))  AS eg(ntxt)
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (VALUES(COALESCE(NULLIF(strpos(ntxt,';'),0),CHAR_LENGTH(ntxt))-1)) AS item(len)
WHERE N = 0 OR token LIKE ';%';
```

**Results:**

```
ItemNumber  ItemIndex  ItemLength  Item
----------- ---------- ----------- -----------
1           1          7           text123
2           9          9            text 456
3           19         9            text 789
4           29         9            text 101
```

A little trimming may be needed for the return item

Comment: Thanks - but this is Progress not PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

Extent / array fields in Progress OpenEdge are **also** shown as separated by a semi-colon when viewed from SQL92, **if** this is an extent / array field, then you can simply use:

`addr[1]`

If it is not, then you can use `instr`, **but** you will need to use the correct [syntax](https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dmsrf%2Finstr.html%23). The first parameter is the string, the second is what you want to find in it. Note the extra `+ ';'` below to ensure the string always ends with a semi-colon:

`substr( addr, 1, instr( addr + ';', ';', 1 ) - 1 )`

If you not only want the first, but the second or the third, then it gits a bit trickier:

```
select
  addr,  
  substring( addr, 1, instr( addr + ';', ';', 1, 1 ) ) as '#1' ,
  case    
     when instr( addr, ';', 1, 1 ) > 0 then
       substring( addr, instr( addr, ';', 1, 1 ), instr( addr + ';', ';', 1, 2 ) - instr( addr, ';', 1, 1 ) )
     else 
       ''
  end as '#2' ,
  case    
     when instr( addr, ';', 1, 2 ) > 0 then 
       substring( addr, instr( addr, ';', 1, 2 ), instr( addr + ';', ';', 1, 3 ) - instr( addr, ';', 1, 2 ) )
     else 
       ''
  end as '#3'  
from ...
```

All of the above has been tested from PDSOE (Eclipse) using the JDBC driver. Assuming OPENQUERY does not corrupt anything along the way, you should be fine.

Comment: I tried the above but receive: OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MyServer" returned message "[DataDirect][ODBC Progress OpenEdge Wire Protocol driver][OPENEDGE]Inconsistent types (7481)".

Comment: You are able to get just the contents of addr? What is the data type of addr? Is it an extent (if not, then you cannot use [1])? Additional, can you query directly (using odbc)? Sometimes it helps to not let OPENQUERY throw extra confusion into the mix.

Comment: I can get to addr yes, it is just varchar.  To be honest, I will just use the outer T-SQL to do this, it will be easier.  I just wanted to see if it was possible using Progress.  Thank you anyway.